# How to send data to expressjs from jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm sending parameters from a browser to a server with jQuery ajax. But I cannot get my params on a server side. Here is my code:

```
// Front-end
    $.post( "/foo", {one: "two"}, function( data ) {
        $( "#cout" ).html( data );
    });


// backend
app.all('/foo', function(req, res) {
    console.log("[req.body] :", req.body);   // [req.body] : undefined
    console.log("[req.params] :", req.params);   // [req.params] : []
});
```

How may I get my params?

**UPD:**

My app.js script:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.all('/foo', function(req, res) {
    console.log("[req.body] :", req.body);
    console.log("[req.params] :", req.params);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: Seems about right, how are you creating the server, and what middleware is added ?

Comment: Just for fun, try adding `app.use(express.bodyParser());` before the static route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Before the `static` middleware.